# Cloud Storage vs Google Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

I have created a google firebase project with an android application.
I have set the DB rules to read and write as true (Just testing)

My question is if I do "My Firebase URL/.json.. I can see the data stored in my realtime database but I cannot see or access the objects stored in my Firebase Storage.

My question is, are these both seperate entities ? How do I access Google Storage ?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realtime Database and Cloud Storage are completely separate products, that both can be accessed through Firebase. The fact that you can access the data in the database, and even how you access it, is pretty much unrelated to whether and how you can access the files in Cloud Storage,

To access the files in Storage, you can either use the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/storage), access them [through the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files) in a way that is allowed by your **Storage** [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/get-started), or you can [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) for each file and open that in any browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My point was just like we can access from real time DB through /,json. can we also access data from firebase storage ? I can see it has some gs:// URL too

Comment: A `gs://` URL is a protocol that most browsers don't speak, so pasting it into the address bar of your browser won't work. The Firebase SDK *does* recognize this type of URL and can read the file, or you can generate a download URL, which starts with `https://` so *can* be read by your browser.